# How to manage external .d.ts dependencies while publishing an NPM module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I am publishing a module to the NPM registry.

It was built with TypeScript (using a `typings` attribute in `package.json` and `"declaration": true` in my `tsconfig.json`.

While building the NPM module, I needed the following `.d.ts` files, which I downloaded via the `typings` tool:

- ES6 Promise
- MQTT.js

When I generate my module and include it in a child project, TypeScript warns me about not using triple slash references in modules. These references were added by TypeScript when I added `"declaration": true` to my `tsconfig.json`.

```
error TS2654:
    Exported external package typings file cannot contain
    tripleslash references.
```

If I remove the references, I will get type errors (or duplicate identifier warnings).

What is the correct way to publish an NPM module which has sub-dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to publish an NPM module which has sub-dependencies

This is changing at the moment. The story for pure ts packages depending on pure ts packages is very clear (more : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html)

However if your package depends upon other .d.ts files for `.js` projects then I recommend you just mentioning to your users to download the definitions for those `.js` projects indepdently.

## More

Whats coming: `.d.ts` NPM packages for `.js` projects. This is very much in flux and things are changing rapidly in this space.